# Flutter - put variable value outside a function

Tags: android, flutter

i'm trying to show the data i retrieve on a function outside of it (to show in a listview of products) but i cant do it because i cant access the variable.

First I open a dialog where i put the order number, when i click a button on this dialog it runs the following code:
(this function is inside a onPressed).

```
        Future loadProdutos() async{
                                    ProdutosList produtosList =
                                        ProdutosList.fromJson(response.data);
                                    print(produtosList.produtos[1].qtd);
                                    print(produtosList.produtos.length);
                                  }

      setState(() {
                                    loadProdutos();
                                    Navigator.pop(context, true);
                                  });
```

So the data its stored on produtoslist, but when I try to use the produtosList length on the listview (for example) like the example below it cant access the data.

Here

```
  child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: produtosList.produtos.length,  <<< //Undefined name 'produtosList'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.dart(undefined_identifi
```

How can I make produtosList accessable from the whole file?
Or to create it outside of the function and use it inside (when i try i cant access the variable inside of the function, maybe because its async).

Heres the full code

```
class OS extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _OSState createState() => _OSState();
}

class _OSState extends State<OS> {
  static _read() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final key = 'operador';
    final value = prefs.getString(key);
    print('saved tester $value');
    String operadorLogado = value;
    return operadorLogado;
  }

  @override
  final _numeroOsController = TextEditingController();
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _read();


    var produtosList1 = <ProdutoOs>[];


    //WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _read());

    // final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    // final key = 'usuario';
    // final value = prefs.getString(key);
    // print('saved $value');
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("OS  Nº  xxx"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                        return AlertDialog(
                            scrollable: true,
                            title: Text('BUSCAR OS'),
                            content: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Form(
                                child: TextFormField(
                                  controller: _numeroOsController,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            actions: [
                              ElevatedButton(
                                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                  primary: Colors.blue,
                                  onPrimary: Colors.white,
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                child: Text("IR"),
                                onPressed: () async {
                                  Response response;
                                  Dio dio = new Dio();
                                  String url =
                                      'http://192.168.15.2:8090/api/getOs';
                                  response = await dio.post(url, data: {
                                    "numeroos": _numeroOsController.text
                                  });

                                  print(response.statusCode);

                             jsonDecode(response);


                                  Future loadProdutos() async {
                                  
                                    ProdutosList produtosList =
                                        ProdutosList.fromJson(response.data);
                                    print(produtosList.produtos[1].qtd);
                                    print(produtosList.produtos.length);
                                  }

                                  setState(() {
                                    loadProdutos();
                                    Navigator.pop(context, true);
                                  });

                               
                                },
                              )
                            ]);
                      });
                },
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.search,
                  size: 26.0,
                ),
              )),
        ],
      ),
      
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 8,
                    child: Text(
                      "CLIENTE:",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 8,
                    child: Text(
                      "STATUS:",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 8.0, 0, 8.0),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: Text("CÓDIGO",
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Text(
                      "QTD",
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 3,
                    child: Text(
                      "FUNCIONÁRIO",
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 4,
                    child: Text(
                      "DESCRIÇÃO",
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Divider(
            height: 5.0,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 3,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 4.0, 0.0, 4.0),
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 2,
                          child: Text(
                            "12345",
                            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 1,
                          child: Text(
                            "12",
                            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 3,
                          child: Text("example",
                              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis
                            
                              ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 4,
                          child: Text(
                              "DESCRIÇÃO DA PEÇA XXXXXX11111111 XXXXXXX",
                              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                }),
          )
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return AlertDialog(
                    scrollable: true,
                    title: Text('ADICIONAR PEÇA'),
                    content: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Form(
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            TextFormField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    actions: [
                      ElevatedButton(
                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            primary: Colors.blue,
                            onPrimary: Colors.white,
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0),
                            ),
                          ),
                          child: Text("IR"),
                          onPressed: () {
                            // your code
                          }),
                    ],
                  );
                });
          },
          child: Icon(Icons.add)),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: print(produtosList.produtos[1].qtd);
print(produtosList.produtos.length);  --> could you please share this data ! if its confidential please replace the content with dummy data

Comment: It will me to understand your exact issue

Comment: Sure, it prints: I/flutter (20658): 4; /flutter (20658): 2;  Its just a test for me to see if the app its receiving the corret data (qtd, in the case) and length of the json.

Comment: produtosList.produtos --> please print this

Comment: It prints: I/flutter (20658): [Instance of 'ProdutoOs', Instance of 'ProdutoOs']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a local variable in class.

For example:

```dart
class PhotosScreen {
  final photos = <Photo>[];

  Future<void> reloadPhotos() async {
    photos.clear();
    photos.addAll(await api.getPhotos());
    setState(() {});
  }
}
```

In your case (you placed a variable to method, not to class):

```dart
var produtosList1 = <ProdutoOs>[];

@override
final _numeroOsController = TextEditingController();
  void initState() {
  super.initState();
}
```

Comment: I tried creating " final produtosList1 = <ProdutoOs>[];" outside of the function but i cant access this inside of the function.

Comment: If you try to change a value - you cannot do this with `final` value. Declare values that can be changed by using `var` word or by type.

Comment: Ok but i sill got "Undefined name 'produtosList1'.", even trying with a simple string variable to test. Could it be related to the async? (my onpressed is a async function cause it runs a Dio code)

Comment: It is called in one class?

Comment: Can you add full class code to the question?